# VBA issue with ending for-loop when cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, web-scraping

I have a successful webscrape that takes a number from column A in excel and enters it into a webpage. The program does a few things, such as log the user in, click several buttons, enter the number, copy/paste the web-page info back into excel(removed from code below bc it isn't neceesary for my question) , and then runs through the next number.
Here is what the numbers look like:

[image]

What I am having issues with is: ending the for
I am thinking something needs to be placed after where I set i=3 to last row, but nothign stops the program. It will just enter the blank number (ie cell A10), which obviously will show an error in the web-page.

```
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
IE.Visible = True


For i = 3 To lastrow

 Set svalue1 = IeDoc.getElementByID("accountNumber")
 svalue1.Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value 'takes the  number out and enters
```

So I have tried adding on Error GoTo 0, i tried writing a line after the svalue and saying if it ="" then exit etc. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
```

To

```
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

---

Side notes:

Use proper page load waits through out and you might be able to remove some of those hardcoded waits

```
While .busy Or .readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Each loop of `input` elements looking for a specific value can be re-written with syntax like:

```
.document.querySelector("input[value=Submit Request]").Click '<change value of value attribute
```

It is generally safer to work of `ie.document` than off an HTMLDocument variable when there is this much clicking and navigating.

```
Dim sheetName As String
sheetName = ws.Range("D10").Value
For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sheet.Name = sheetName Then
        MsgBox "ERROR: This Numb has already been formulated"
        NewName = InputBox("Please Rename:")
        sheet.Name = NewName
        duplicate = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next sheet
```

This cuts down on accessing the sheet to receive the Range("D10") value. Removes potential for bugs by using explicit sheet reference, the `ws` in front of `ws.Range("D10").Value`; this should be done through out. And you want to check against `sheet.Name` not `Activesheet` in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

`ws.rows.Count` will get you a count of the max number of rows possible in a sheet (over 1,000,000). Then doing an `End(xlDown)` will attempt to go further down, which will still be that same number.

There are a couple of ways get the proper row.

If you can guarantee that your numbers always start on A3 and that you'll never have any blanks from A3 to the intended end then, this will work
`lastrow = ws.Range("A3").end(xlDown).row`

Alternatively if you will have gaps just change `xlDown` to `xlUp` to find the first row from the bottom that has values as QHarr suggests.